# Is intellisense the same in visual studio code as it is in visual studio Professional?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is intellisense the same in visual studio code as it is in visual studio Professional? Or is it a watered-down version?
P.S. I'm more interested at this point in Javascript if that matters.

Comment: Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio (non-Code) are two completely different products. Rosly might be powering C# intellisense but for javascript there's likely completely different engines that is providing intellisense support. Basically, I think the answer to your question is just "No".

Comment: Do you think it is just as 'good'? or are there missing features that might prove cumbersome?

Comment: I am voting to close. Since the two are definitely different, the "watered-down" sounds subjective here. Try to ask a more specific question, e.g. about features you are interested in.

Comment: Try it out, VS Code is free. The real question is wether there are features that YOU are missing. I use both on a daily basis, and for JS and the likes I prefer Code over VS

Comment: Visual Studio Code is to Visual Studio what JavaScript is to Java (or what carpet is to car).